# Using CASE WHEN Expression with where condition SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, spring-boot

I have my new Spring Boot project with SQL Server and I need to replace my MySQL native query on the Repository method in my old project with SQL Server native query. It's a complex query with the case when expression in where condition. When I try testing that query in SQL Server Management Studio it shows errors like the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76OpH.png)

And here's my old native query use with MySQL on the Repository method I want to replace it with SQL Server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENB06.png)
Please help me to find the solution.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `CASE`, as you state in your title, is an **expression**, not a statement. It returns a scalar value *not* a boolean result. Honsetly, just don't use a `CASE` in a `WHERE`, it's not SARGable, stick to explicit boolean logic with `AND`s and `OR`s.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have and what you should have posted as text within your question. As text it becomes searchable and copyable by people trying to help YOU.

```
case when @num = 1 then p.merchant_name = @query else 1=1 end
```

CASE is an expression in TSQL. It is not a control-of-flow construct like it is in many other languages. To use an "optional" filter, you need to construct a boolean expression using CASE which handles the "optional" attribute correctly. Often this is done with a bit more complexity using CASE like this:

```
case when @num = 1 and p.merchant_name <> @query then 0 else 1 end = 1
```

So here, CASE is used to return a value that can be tested in a comparison. There is no magic in using 0 or 1. Use any values of any type.

- When @num is 1 and the values do NOT match, the THEN branch (0) is returned.
- When @num is 1 and the values match, the ELSE branch (1) is returned.
- When @num is anything but 1, the ELSE branch (1) is returned.

So when the CASE expression returns 0 (really - anything but 1), the row is ignored (removed from the resultset).

Given that your query is actually constructed in an application, you should considering dynamically building the query and adding parameters as needed. That will likely generate a more efficient query that can be better optimized by the database engine. Alternatively you can review this [kitchen sink discussion](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) and Erland's discussion of [dynamic search conditions](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). TBH it looks like someone used `@num` as a kludge to avoid adding parameters for the eight specific filter values. If I want to filter on both merchant name and store name, I can't with this approach.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. Let me try the way you recommended. I just wonder why MySQL can archive that, but SQL Server can't